# Limit UISplitViewController detail view to a specific orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to limit the detail view to landscape orientation on iPhone and let the master view to use any orientation.

So I added the following to the detail view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called but has no effect. `shouldAutorotate` is not called. How can I achieve the desired behaviour on iOS 8?